# Is it possible to trigger/call another program when kafka HdfsSinkConnector finish

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, impala

I want to trigger the impala refresh job when kafka HdfsSinkConnector task finish it. Is it possible to get notification when task complete or any other way to trigger/call my other program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDFS has an inotify feature which essentially translates those log entries into events that can be consumed.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6634

Here's a Java based example: https://github.com/onefoursix/hdfs-inotify-example

Alternatively, rather than having Oozie monitor many directories and waste resources, a script can execute 'hdfs dfs -ls -R /folder|grep|sed' every minute or so but that's still not event based, so it depends how fast of a reaction you need vs how easy you can implement/use the inotify API

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/HDFS-Best-way-to-trigger-execution-at-File-arrival/td-p/163423